# jquery load page fragment loading double div ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#cart').load('shop.php/ #cart');
```

So i want to reload the cart section of my page but it is loading it inside the original div id like so:

```
<div id="cart">
    <div id="cart">
       // everything loaded fine here
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want it to display the one div, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$('#cart').load('shop.php/');`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do everything correct. However, [loading of page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in jQuery works as follows:

> ```
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
> ```
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of *ajax/test.html*,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

So it *will* include the container as well. To include the inner contents only use the following:

```
$("#cart").load("shop.php/ #cart > *");​​​​​​​​​​​
```