# Filter strings with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use $.get to load pages without reloading the page.

```
<script>
$('#top_links a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').empty();


    $.get(link, { }, 
        function(data) {
            $('#content').empty().append(data);
        }
    )
});
</script>
```

This works but the entire requested page is getting stuffed into `#content`. Instead of detecting the ajax request and filtering the data on the server-side, I would like to do it client-side. Is there a way to use javascript to effectively filter the string so that I only get certain divs? The content that I want to preserve will all be contained inside of a div called `#content` ( Im just trying to swap the current page's `#content` with the requested page's `#content`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method with loading of page fragments approach:

```
$("#content").load(link + " #content > *");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here we can use `> *` in order to include the inner HTML of the `#content` block only without surrounding it with `<div id="content"></div>` (check more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233142/jquery-load-page-fragment-loading-double-div-ids/)).

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the data returned from `get` in the same way you do the elements on the page.

For instance:

```
$('#content').replaceWith($(data).find("#content"));
```